# Generate jfd from java

Tags: java, user-interface

In the project I'm currently working on we use JFormDesigner to edit gui forms. Some of forms were edited manually (in java files) and now differ much from their jfd sources.
Is there a way to somehow generate jfd file from java? Only forms are needed, I agree to lose generated code as there is not much of it.